# printing array + visual counter without too much repeating code in c#

Tags: c#, structure, dry

```
Console.Clear();
        for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
        {
            Console.Write($"\rRandomising lotteryball:  {i}  ");

            Thread.Sleep(20);
        }
        Console.WriteLine($"\r\rRandomising lotteryball: {lotteryBalls[0]}      ");

        for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
        {
            Console.Write($"\rRandomising lotteryball:  {i}  ");

            Thread.Sleep(20);
        }
        Console.WriteLine($"\r\rRandomising lotteryball: {lotteryBalls[1]}    ");
        for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
        {
            Console.Write($"\rRandomising lotteryball:  {i}  ");

            Thread.Sleep(20);
        }
        Console.WriteLine($"\r\rRandomising lotteryball: {lotteryBalls[2]}    ");
```

So you see that im using a visual counter that seems to "freeze" at a "random" number then move on to the next line to create another randomised ball.

So i have an idea that i would do a for-loop printing the arrays and add the counter within the loop instad.. but how would i go about doing this structure wise?

Answer (score 3):

```
Console.Clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < lotteryBalls.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j <= 100; j++)
            {
                Console.Write($"\rRandomising lotteryball:  {j}  ");
                Thread.Sleep(20);
            }
            Console.WriteLine($"\r\rRandomising lotteryball:   {lotteryBalls[i]}       ");
        }
```

I managed to solve it with experimenting a little more! Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

Best solution structure-wise is to move the repeated code to a method.
But I've noticed that you are not generating any random number at all.
If generating a random number is intended (though nothing is totally random cuz it actually depends on a generating algorithm after all) then use this code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] lotteryBalls = new int[101];
            for (int i = 0; i < lotteryBalls.Length; i++) { lotteryBalls[i] = i; }
            
            Console.Clear();
            Randomisinglotteryball(lotteryBalls);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }


        // Following method prints the coutnter then a random member from int[] array to screen
        private static void Randomisinglotteryball(int[] lotteryBalls)
        {
            int randomBallindex = new Random().Next(lotteryBalls.Length);
            for (int i = 0; i < lotteryBalls.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.Write($"\rRandomising lotteryball:  {i}  ");
                Thread.Sleep(20);
            }
            Console.WriteLine($"\r\nRandom Ball Number:\t{lotteryBalls[randomBallindex]}\r\n");
        }
    }
}
```